# Hiking in the Sapa mountains Vietnam

Tags: hiking, children

Is altitude a problem in this area - Sapa is at 1500m so any thing over that is going to be heading into intermediate altitude territory.  We are trekking with a 13 year old and hope to do 14 Km to a home stay.  Is that realistic?  Thank you Ruth

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give more background on the experience of the kids and what altitude you think you are going to reach in what time span.

Answer (score 2):

I spend a few weeks in Vietnam a few years back and one fo the first things I did was to climb Fansipan (3,143 metres). The place itself is fine. Altitude shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't have a severe problem with altitude of course which I'd say it's not normal. Various touristic activities include walking around and about the villages. Walks are not strenuous and you can get food and drinks all around the place.

It's a really enjoyable place actually and I've been meaning to bring family over for a few years. We are hoping to make with our current 20 month old daughter.